# Assign String Array to Class Property

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a hard time setting and calling a String array class property properly.

**Current Class Property**

```
Private pNames() As String

'pNames Properties
Public Property Get Names() As String
    Names() = pNames
End Property
Public Property Let Names(Names As String)
    pNames() = Names
End Property
```

**Current Compilation Error**

> Compile Error: Expected array

on the below line, specifically highlighting `LBound`:

```
For Loop1 = LBound(EditCategories.Names) To UBound(EditCategories.Names)
```

How can I register this property properly as a String array?

---

**What I've Tried**

`Public Property Let Names()(Names As String)` which highlights the empty parentheses and throws:

> Argument required for Property Let or Property Set

`Public Property Let Names(Names() As String)` which highlights the entire line and throws:

> Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent, or property procedure has an optional parameter, a ParamArray, or an invalid Set final parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backing field is a `String` array. VBA syntax for typed arrays is a bit weird/inconsistent.

Backing field:

```
Private pNames() As String
```

Property:

```
Public Property Get Names() As String()
```

Notice the `String()` parens - that would be illegal in the `Private pNames` declaration - go figure.

The problem is that you can't assign to an array like this, so there's no way a `Property Let` accessor can be legal - this wouldn't compile:

```
Public Property Let Names(ByRef values As String())
```

Welcome to the joys of typed arrays in VBA. Just expose it as a `Variant` and be done with it:

```
Public Property Get Names() As Variant
```

```
Public Property Let Names(ByRef values As Variant)
```

Comment: FWIW - although `Public Property Let Names(ByRef values As String())` is invalid, switching it to `Public Property Let Names(ByRef values() As String)` will compile, but then you get stuck when you try to use it, e.g. `x.Names = y` (where `y` is a String array) gives the "Can't assign to an array" compile error.  VBA can be frustrating at times!

Comment: For most values of "times", @YowE3K!

Comment: @FreeMan For all of the values of "most"!